# Why is the trailing space at the end of this PHP include preventing the AJAX http_response_code() from returning the correct value?

Tags: php, ajax

This simple, simple code fails to return HTTP response code 500 if there is a blank line at the end of a required PHP file in an AJAX POST endpoint, called `cursed.php`. With the blank line I always get status code 200. When I remove the blank line I get status code 500, as expected.

Here is the smallest code that reproduces it for me:

`index.php`

```
<script>
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", 'ajax.php', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        console.log(this.status);
    }
    xhr.send();
</script>
```

`ajax.php`

```
<?
require_once('./cursed.php');
http_response_code(500);
die("foo");
?>
```

And this cursed file: `cursed.php`

```
<?
?>
```

See that blank line at the end of `cursed.php`? If I leave it, the callback always returns 200 OK. If I remove it, it fails and prints status 500. I've googled the heck out of this and found nothing except discussions about why you should or should not have blank lines at the end of files.

I'm running PHP7.2 on Ubuntu 18.x.

Comment: Not sure but with the blank line it returns "something" and without it returns nothing.

Comment: Also `<?
?>` short tags are deprecated and may not be supported on your system, might be something or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at the effect of your `require` statement. When PHP encounters an `include` or `require` statement it terminates the current PHP block with an implicit `?>`. Then it starts the included file, embedding what it finds. Then it starts a new PHP block with an implicit `<?php` (or `<?`).

With a trailing line after the closing `?>` in your included file it  gives this result:

```
<?
?>
<?                                 // require statement here               
?>

<?
http_response_code(500);
die("foo");
?>
```

Notice that blank line in the middle? That is treated as output to be sent to the client. Since it appears before your `http_response_code(500);` the headers are already sent and PHP can't change the status code. Ergo, your response is a status of 200 with content of a blank line.

Omit the trailing `?>` in your PHP code files. If PHP doesn't find a closing delimiter it will assume an implicit `?>` after the very last line, thus eliminating the problem.

From the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php)

> If a file contains only PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP
> closing tag at the end of the file. This prevents accidental
> whitespace or new lines being added after the PHP closing tag, which
> may cause unwanted effects because PHP will start output buffering
> when there is no intention from the programmer to send any output at
> that point in the script.

Comment: Brilliant walk-through! I didn't realize the headers are sent with the first output (I guess I just assumed it was all batched up and sent later...). It makes complete sense when explained this way, rather than "just don't do it." Thanks!